# Java decimalFormat RoundingMode

Tags: java

I need to archive this: (basically **num1 * num2 = num3** and **num1** and **num2** are given)

```
1) 10.62 * 4.0 = 42.48 
2) 14.89 * 8.5 = 126.56 
3) 13.21 * 6.0 = 79.26 
4) 16.55 * 7.35 = 121.64 
5) 18.62 * 9.0 = 167.58 
6) 9.47 * 15.3 = 144.89
7) 6.58 * 3.0 = 19.74 
8) 18.32 * 5.4 = 98.93 
9) 12.15 * 2.9 = 35.24 
10) 3.98 * 4.8 = 19.10
```

This exercise is to practice formatting/rounding string/number.

So I used:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(num3));
```

and got everything right but the `9) 12.15 * 2.9 = 35.24` , I got `35.23` instead of `35.24`
The default RoundingMode of DecimalFormat is HALF_EVEN, if I use RoundingMode.UP I will get this right **35.24** but the others results will be messed so I am stuck...

What should I use in order to get the expected result?

Comment: Have you tried `RoundingMode.CEILING` or `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

Comment: HALF_UP not worked, CEILING will messed up other results.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RoundingMode UNNECESSARY`, will solve your problem. Additionally you can catch exceptions and specify output manually if needed.